# Why does Ubuntu give "could not resolve host for external urls" called from code?

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dns, laravel

I have tow servers running Ubuntu, and I have hosted sites on both of them.

Some are Laravel and some are Python sites.

Suddenly, **on both servers**, and despite of code being unchanged for a while, I get ***random errors*** like these:

```
Could not resolve host: api.x.ai
Could not resolve host: api.y.com
Could not resolve host: api.z.sa
Max retries exceeded with url: api.g.com
```

**System details:** `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

They appear very very often but not on 100% of visitors actions. There is some random thing happening

So what could be wrong?

Please assist because I followed some instructions to disable ipv6 and clear DNS cache and rebooting the servers and I got no results.

Thanks!

Comment: @guiverc added, thanks!

Comment: @guiverc I made a typo while writing the tags, I wanted to tag ubunto but it's not allowed, I changed them

Comment: I guess `Max retries exceeded with url:...` is comming from a Python script using the `requests` module ... If so, then you might want to rephrase your question accordingly as it should then be more Python focused than it is Ubuntu focused.

Comment: @Raffa code is unchanged for months, and now the errors are showing in both websites, I think something weird from the server is causing this but I can't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to use these when calling the external APIs:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
```

This worked successfully. And for the last error, seems like the service provider blocked my server by mistake and I contacted support and it was solved.